# Jquery stop repeat my code with after?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my input and my Jquery :

Basically I have this code :

**HTML**:

```
<form id="formUser">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-6 columns">
                    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">First name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="small-6 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="fisrtName" placeholder="First name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check"><label for="checkbox"><p>I accept the review agreement</p></label>
        <button type="submit" class="button join">Let's Go !</button>    
    </div>      
</form>
```

**JS** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#formUser").submit(function(){
            if(!$('input[name="fisrtName"]').val()) {
                $('input[name="fisrtName"]').addClass("error");
                $('input[name="fisrtName"]').after("<small class='error'>Invalid entry</small>");
            }
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I have this [image: probleme]

When I click several time on the button... the error class is repeat ..
How can i stop the repeat or incrase the actual class error ?

Comment: Just add the html into the html file and then use `.toggle()` to show/hide the error. There is no reason to use `.after()` here

Comment: @JeffShaver i have lot of input , did i always need to repeat "if(!$('input[name="myname"]').val()) {" or there is more simple when we have lot of input ?

Comment: `fisrtName`... surely that should be `**first** Name` ? ;)

Comment: My point was to add the `<small class="error">Invalid Entry</small>` directly into the HTML file (not via JS). Then use JS to hide/show the error

Comment: Yeah, i use this simple solution, thx. @gvee you right !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should be doing something like this

```
$("#formUser").submit(function(){

  var $element = $('internal[name="fisrtName]');
  // ^ save this much faster ^
  // ^ you have spelt firstName wrong also ^

  // check val and check next element isn't error
  if($element.val() && $element.next().hasClass('error') === false) {
    $element.addClass('error').after("<small class='error'>Invalid entry</small>");
  } else {
     // now remove it if you need to
  }
  return false;
});
```

Hope it helps.

You should always cache your elements

By doing this:

```
$('internal[name="fisrtName');
$('internal[name="fisrtName');
$('internal[name="fisrtName');
```

You're calling the jQuery function **3** times when you do **not** need to.

Comment: also, the `[...]` selector is unclosed

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 if($('input[name="fisrtName"]').find('.error').length==0)
 $('input[name="fisrtName"]').after("<small class='error'>Invalid entry</small>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Or:

```
var $firstName = $('input[name="fisrtName"]');
if (!$firstName.hasClass("error")) {
    $firstName.addClass("error");
    $firstName.after("<small class='error'/>");
}
$firstName.find("small.error").text("Invalid entry");
```

Comment: Please cache elements :(

Comment: Alright, it's a slight improvement, but it doesn't change the result

Comment: Yeah, it won't change the result, but that wasn't the point. This will also have the same result http://jsfiddle.net/Y3LQX/ Anyway **+1** for edit :)

Answer (score -2):

Try to change your code with this, I have aded the line "$('small.error').remove();"

```
$.q("#formUser").submit(function(){
    if(!$.q('input[name="fisrtName"]').val()) {
        $.q('small.error').remove();
        $.q('input[name="fisrtName"]').addClass("error");
        $.q('input[name="fisrtName"]').after("<small class='error'>Invalid entry</small>");
    }
return false;
});
```